# Jumpy Nav bar upon changing height (sticky property)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sticky

I'm having a strange problem that I dont know how to deal with.

I basically want to decrease the size of my navbar when the user starts scrolling down the page but due to this change of height, the navbar makes a jumpy effect and if the page's height is 100% of the available space + a slight scroll, the navbar gets kinda stuck in between two states. Problem illustrated at the bottom.

I have tried programically scrolling the page before setting `scrolled` state to true to prevent the navbar from resizing but that was horrible.

This is my window.onscroll event:

```
  handleScroll = () => {
    const { scrolled } = this.state;
    console.log(window.scrollY, window.pageYOffset);
    if (window.pageYOffset >= 10 && !scrolled) {
      this.setState({ scrolled: true });
    } else if (window.pageYOffset == 0 && scrolled) {
      this.setState({ scrolled: false });
    }
  };
```

and this is my css:

```
nav {
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  position: sticky;
}

nav.scrolled {
  height: 80px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, changing the y-offset because the elementes above change height while listening to it is sure to cause bugs. I think you'll want to lock the height of the flexible height nav at the top. This link will also help you clean up the scroll listener a bit: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/ Also, maybe don't use the y-offset of the element but the sum of the heights of elements above it.

Comment: just a suggestion. Add transition to nav.scrolled as well.

Comment: @admcfajn I'll have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar challenge, where I wanted to move the navigation from a static position to a fixed. So the navigation is at a static position on the page, and as soon the user reaches a breakpoint, the navigation would change into a fixed position, so that it is always visible and at the top of the screen. further more, the height changed too.

the solution I had for this, as the main problem is the change in the overall page height, to add a placeholder element with the exact height of the navigation, and show it as soon as the navigation gets sticky.

So the solution is, just to ensure, the overall height does not change.

For example, if you would change your css to this, you should not be seeing this effect (not my suggested solution!), as you would not change the overall height, and therefore you would not trigger multiple scroll and rerender issues:

```
nav {
  height: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  position: sticky;
}

nav.scrolled {
  height: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}
```

you could get better insights, if you placed some `console.log` when toggeling the state of `scrolled`.

Comment: Yeah that solution will remove the jumpy effect but the point is that the user should be able to see the entire navbar at all times hence the `sticky` property

Comment: I dont exactly get what you mean by the comment? I did not suggest to remove sticky, or to hide the navbar at any time. I said, that as soon as you change the height, you change the height of the complete document, which causes this error. so if you would for example reduce the height but add the subtracted value somewhere else, you would not get this bug.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to add this placeholder element just now to see how it works. I was commenting on the css solution by the way with the `padding-bottom: 70px`

Comment: yeah and the solution with the padding should not hide anything, or does it?

Comment: It doesn't hide anything actually, i just removed `top:0` by mistake so the sticky won't work but now it does. Now there's just 50 extra pixels of black :P